# Loosing data from Source to Sink in Copy Data

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory

In my MS Azure datafactory, I have a rest API connection to a nested JSON dataset. 
The Source "Preview data" shows all data. (7 orders from the online store)

In the "Activity Copy Data", is the menu tab "Mapping" where I map JSON fields with the sink SQL table columns. If I under "Collection Reference" I select None, all 7 orders are copied over. 
But if I want the nested metadata, I select the meta field in "Collection Reference", then I get my nested data, in multiple order lines, each with a one metadata point, but I only get data from 1 order, not 7

I think I have a reason for my problem. One of the fields in the nested meta data, is both a string and array. But I still don't have a solution

[sceen shot of meta data](https://imgur.com/wHKvFqS)

Comment: I think that you are talking about meta.value which I see as string and also as an array . Can you please the table structure in the DB side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sense is right,it caused by your nested structure meta data. Based on the [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-schema-mapping) of Collection Reference property:

> If you want to iterate and extract data from the objects inside an
>   array field with the same pattern and convert to per row per object,
>   specify the JSON path of that array to do cross-apply. This property
>   is supported only when hierarchical data is source.

same pattern is key point here, I think. However, your data inside metadata array are not same as your screenshot.

[image]

My workaround is using Azure Blob Storage to make a transition, `REST API ---> Azure Blob Storage--->Your sink dataset`. Inside Blob Storage Dataset, you could flatten the incoming JSON data with `Cross-apply nested JSON array` setting:

[image]

You could refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/@gary.strange/flattening-json-in-azure-data-factory-2f2130794258) to learn about this feature. Then you could copy the flatten data into your destination.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Just as soon as I can open a blob storage. Can't with my current credentials, so my boss must step in.

Comment: @ErikWarming Sure!