# Azure Data Factory complex JSON source (nested arrays) to Azure Sql Database?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON source document that will be uploaded to Azure blob storage regularly. The customer wants to have this input written to Azure Sql Database using Azure Data Factory. The JSON is however complex with many nested arrays and so  far I have not be able to find a way to flatten the document. Perhaps this is not supported/possible?

```
[
{
"ActivityId": 1,
    "Header": {},
    "Body": [{
        "1stSubArray": [{
            "Id": 456,
            "2ndSubArray": [{
                "Id": "abc",
                "Descript": "text",
                "3rdSubArray": [{
                    "Id": "def",
                    "morefields": "text"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "ghi",
                    "morefields": "sample"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
]
```

I need to flatten it:

```
ActivityId, Id, Id, Descript, Id, morefields
1, 456, abc, text1, def, text
1, 456, abc, text2, ghi, sample
1, 456, xyz, text3, jkl, textother
1, 456, xyz, text4, mno, moretext
```

There could be 8+ flat records per ActivityId. Anyone out there that has seen this and found a way to resolve using Azure Data Factory Copy Data?

Comment: Could you follow this general approach? Instead of a Web Activity you could use a Lookup Activity to get the contents of the Blob and then pass it as a parameter into the stored proc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962908/5070440

Comment: If you are frustrated with ADF's pure lack of JSON Parsing ability and the lack of multi-collection selection when it comes to parsing JSON, Please upvote this: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23432697-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past,you could follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@gary.strange/flattening-json-in-azure-data-factory-2f2130794258) and my previous case:[Loosing data from Source to Sink in Copy Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553533/loosing-data-from-source-to-sink-in-copy-data/57686714#57686714) to set `Cross-apply nested JSON array` option in Blob Storage Dataset. However,it disappears now.

Instead,[Collection Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#explicit-mapping) is applied for array items schema mapping in copy activity.

[image]

But based on my test,only one array can be flattened in a schema. Multiple arrays can be referenced—returned as one row containing all of the elements in the array. However, only one array can have each of its elements returned as individual rows. This is the current limitation with `jsonPath settings`.

[image]

As workaround,you can first convert json file with nested objects into CSV file using Logic App and then you can use the CSV file as input for Azure Data factory. Please refer this [doc](https://adatis.co.uk/converting-json-with-nested-arrays-into-csv-in-azure-logic-apps-by-using-array-variable/) to understand how Logic App can be used to convert nested objects in json file to CSV. Surely,you could also make some efforts on the sql database side,such as SP which is mentioned in the comment by @GregGalloway.

---

Just for summary,unfortunately,the "Collection reference" only works for one level down in the array structure which is not suitable for @Emrikol. Finally,@Emrikol  abandoned Data Factory and has built an app to the work.

Comment: yes I had already tested using the "Collection reference" and unfortunately the cross-apply only works for one level down in the array structure. FYI, we have abandoned Data Factory for now and I have built an app to the work I needed done.

Comment: @Emrikol Ok,i tried to summarizd your final solution in my answer.If you don't mind, would you pls accept the answer for others' reference.Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Database has some capable JSON shredding abilities including [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which shreds JSON, and [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which returns scalar values from JSON.  Being as you already have Azure SQL DB in your architecture, it would make sense to use it rather than add additional components.

So why not adopt an ELT pattern where you use Data Factory to insert the JSON into a table in Azure SQL DB and then call a stored procedure task to shred it?  Some sample SQL based on your example:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[
{
  "ActivityId": 1,
  "Header": {},
  "Body": [
    {
      "1stSubArray": [
        {
          "Id": 456,
          "2ndSubArray": [
            {
              "Id": "abc",
              "Descript": "text",
              "3rdSubArray": [
                {
                  "Id": "def",
                  "morefields": "text"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "ghi",
                  "morefields": "sample"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Id": "xyz",
              "Descript": "text",
              "3rdSubArray": [
                {
                  "Id": "jkl",
                  "morefields": "textother"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "mno",
                  "morefields": "moretext"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]'

--SELECT @json j

-- INSERT INTO yourTable ( ...
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.ActivityId' ) AS ActivityId,
    JSON_VALUE ( a1.[value], '$.Id' ) AS Id1,
    JSON_VALUE ( a2.[value], '$.Id' ) AS Id2,
    JSON_VALUE ( a2.[value], '$.Descript' ) AS Descript,
    JSON_VALUE ( a3.[value], '$.Id' ) AS Id3,
    JSON_VALUE ( a3.[value], '$.morefields' ) AS morefields

FROM OPENJSON( @json ) j
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( j.[value], '$."Body"' ) AS m
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( m.[value], '$."1stSubArray"' ) AS a1
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( a1.[value], '$."2ndSubArray"' ) AS a2
                CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( a2.[value], '$."3rdSubArray"' ) AS a3;
```

As you can see, I've used `CROSS APPLY` to navigate multiple levels.  My results:

[image: My results]