# Map Nested Array to Sink Columns

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm currently working with a survey API to retrieve results and store them in our data warehouse (SQL database). The results are returned as a JSON object, which includes array ("submissions"), containing each individual's responses. An individual submission contains an array ("answers") with each answer to the questions in the survey.

I would like each submission to be one row in one table.

I will provide some very simple data examples and am just looking for a general way to approach this problem. I certainly am not looking for an entire solution.

The API returns a response like this:

```
{
  "surveyName": "Sample Survey",
  "count": 2,
  "submissions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "created": "2021-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
      "answers": [
        {
           "question_id": 1,
           "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
           "question_id": 2,
           "answer": 5
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "created": "2021-01-02T12:00:00.000Z",
      "answers": [
        {
           "question_id": 1,
           "answer": "No"
        },
        {
           "question_id": 2,
           "answer": 4
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Essentially, I want to add a row into a SQL table where the columns are: id, created, answer1, answer2. Within the Sink tab of the Copy Data activity, I cannot figure out how to essentially say, "If question_id = 1, map the answer to column answer1. If question_id = 2, map the answer to column answer2."

Will I likely have to use a Data Flow to handle this sort of mapping? If so, can you think of the general steps included in that type of flow?

Comment: Check this method out uses native SQL JSON abilities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175144/1527504

Comment: Yes, I would use a data flow and utilize a Derived Column to set the proper value using either an iif() statement or case() statement.

Comment: Please upvote this for nested json array handling in ADF: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23432697-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a similar solution, I'll post the general idea on how I solved this problem, thanks to the suggestion from @mark-kromer-msft.

[image]

First of all, the portion of my pipeline where I obtained the JSON files is not included. For that, I had to use an Until loop to paginate through this particular endpoint in order to obtain all submission results. I used a Copy Data activity to create JSON files in blob storage for each page. After that, I created a Data Flow.

I had to first flatten the "submissions" array in order to separate each submission into a separate row. I then used Derived Column to pull out each answer to a separate column. Here's what that looks like:

[image]

Here's one example of an Expression:

```
find(submissions.answers, equals(#item.question_id, '1')).answer
```

Finally, I just had to create the mapping in the last step (Sink) in order to map my derived columns.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach would be to use the native JSON abilites of Azure SQL DB. Use a Stored Proc task, pass the JSON in as a parameter and shred it in the database using `OPENJSON`:

```
-- Submission level
-- INSERT INTO yourTable ( ...
SELECT
    s.surveyName,
    s.xcount,
    s.submissions    
FROM OPENJSON( @json )
WITH (
    surveyName  VARCHAR(50)     '$.surveyName',  
    xcount      INT             '$.count',
    submissions NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON 
) s
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( s.submissions ) so;


-- Question level, additional CROSS APPLY and JSON_VALUEs required
-- INSERT INTO yourTable ( ...
SELECT
    'b' s,
    s.surveyName,
    s.xcount,
    --s.submissions,
    JSON_VALUE ( so.[value], '$.id' ) AS id,
    JSON_VALUE ( so.[value], '$.created' ) AS created,
    JSON_VALUE ( a.[value], '$.question_id' ) AS question_id,
    JSON_VALUE ( a.[value], '$.answer' ) AS answer

FROM OPENJSON( @json )
WITH (
    surveyName  VARCHAR(50) '$.surveyName',  
    xcount      INT             '$.count',
    submissions NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON 
) s
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( s.submissions ) so
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( so.[value], '$.answers' ) a;
```

Results at submission and question level:

[image: JSON results]

Full script with sample JSON [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/24892e2560aad6a1477d7c01aa56eb76).